# Properly create and customise a web app using Visual Studio 2015 C# MVC template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C# web, I want to know how to properly create a web app using 
Visual Studio 2015 MVC templates, and being able to customise some of its code. I want to both practice C# web and clean code...

So I have 2 projects, one for Domain and another which is the Web App.

For example: in my domain I have a class named `User` with the following code (it is aimed at users who speak Spanish so error messages are in Spanish):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Domain
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Nombre de Usuario")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Nombre de Usuario es obligatorio.")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Correo Electrónico")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Correo Electrónico es obligatorio.")]
        [StringLength(45)]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Contraseña")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Contraseña es obligatoria.")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El número de caracteres de {0} debe ser al menos {2}.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Confirmar Contraseña")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [NotMapped]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "La contraseña y la contraseña de confirmación no coinciden.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public bool Locked { get; set; } = false;

        public bool ConfirmedAccount { get; set; } = false;

        [DisplayName("Perfil")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Perfil es obligatorio.")]
        public Profile Profile { get; set; }

        private User() { }

        public User(string userName, string email, string password, string confirmPassword, Profile profile)
        {
            UserName = userName;
            Email = email;
            Password = password;
            ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword;
            Profile = profile;
        }
    }
}
```

Before continuing, any suggestions about this code will be very welcome!

I want to use ResetPasswordViewModel, ForgotPasswordViewModel, ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel, and many other functionalities that come with MVC templates (you can see them inside AccountViewModels.cs) without programming them myself (that is the idea of using a template isn't it?), but I also want to have my own User class...

Reading the template code, I've found that ApplicationUser class inside IdentityModels.cs would have the logic for User the template applies, It also has a commentary telling me that if I want any other User properties added, they should be added here. But I don't think it would be a good idea to have Business bound code inside the web app, what if (hypothetically speaking) tomorrow I want to make the same application on another platform? (and by the way, why does the template encourage to have the business code inside the web app in the first place??)

I hope you get the idea by now, how to use my own User code to work properly with the MVC template? For example to work along with the class AccountViewModels.cs.

I know those are a lots of questions (I've got plenty more)... As I said, I'm new to this and want to get the hand of it, any suggestions on how to improve my code is welcome.

Regards

Comment: would be better to copy and paste code into your question

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5 done, sorry.

Comment: @SteveGreene thanks! didn't know that existed, I'll post my question there, seems more fit to it.